# compare 2 arrays and wrap the output in quotes using powershell

Tags: powershell

In a directory there will be 2 type of files with same name but different extension for eg:1.png , 1.txt, test_76.png,test_76.txt, test_70.png. In this case test_70.png dosent have its .txt counterpart.I am using this code

```
$scL = dir *.txt | select Basename 
$SList = @($scL -notmatch "MICRO")

$pList = dir *.png | select Basename
$PList = @($pList -notmatch "MICRO")

Compare-Object $PList $SList | ForEach-Object {$_.InputObject} | out-file result.txt
```

but i am unable to get the desired output that is test_70.png in the output file.Also i want to wrap the output inside the text file in double quotes i.e; the outfile should contain entry like this "test_70.png". Can anyone throw light on what am i missing in the compare-object cmdlet.

Comment: you should use -append after the out-file. Each element it is iterating and it should append it to the file instead of creating a new file. use`out-file -append result.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your InputObject is a file object so you will need to access the name. Also in Powershell you can access the properties of the the items in a collection directly. Something like this:

```
(Compare-Object $PList $SList).InputObject.Name | % {"`"$_`""} | Out-File result.txt
```